# Report Formula - Percentage per row per column (not entire table)

Tags: reporting, formula

I cannot find ANY help with what proper references to use for this.  If my report has only one column to the matrix (first screenshot), the following Formula works to product percentages per row in the one column.  If I have MORE than one column, it produces the data based on ALL columns (100% for the entire table, not per column).   Can someone guide me on how to adjust the formula to work "per column" so each column totals 100%?

Formula:

```
RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL( RowCount, ROW_GRAND_SUMMARY, COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

Screen 1 = one column, no problem:
[image: No problem]

Screen 2 = problem:
[image: Problem]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've run into the same exact situation. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DKhn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to reference the correct column variable in the function to make it work:

Originally THIS

```
RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL( RowCount, ROW_GRAND_SUMMARY, **COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY**)
```

now becomes THIS

```
RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, ROW_GRAND_SUMMARY, **CLOSE_DATE**)
```

This gives 100% totals per column instead of only at the Summary.

Comment: Unbelievably, over a year later, this is a problem yet again.  I cannot fathom how to get the FIELD NAME that it expects, apparently.  The Column field is "PB UTP Summary (Client)".  I've tried every iteration of the underscored version of it I can think of - it won't parse.   >:-(   PB_UTP_Summary_Client, and various others.  With and without __c.  With parentheses.   (sigh)

Comment: you need to summarize the field.  `My_Field__c:AVG` or `My_Field__c:SUM`, etc.