# Formula that calculates the percentage of a column in a report

Tags: formula, reporting, report-formula

I have a Salesforce report that is grouped by a field called Forecast Category, it is a picklist field, it also has a Quota amount which is a currency field. The requirement is to have a new column in the report that stores a currency value, the logic is the following:

1. If the Forecast category is "Closed", the new column should be 50% of the Quota amount.
2. If the Forecast category is "Pipeline", the new column should be 20% of the Quota amount.

I've tried creating the new column as a formula, but I'm not getting the desired result, here is the approach I've been using:

IF(ForecastingItem.ForecastCategoryName = "Closed", ForecastingQuota.QuotaAmount:UNIQUE * 0.5, IF(ForecastingItem.ForecastCategoryName = "Pipeline", ForecastingQuota.QuotaAmount:UNIQUE * 0.2, 1))

[image]

I'll appreciate any guidance you can give me with this.

Comment: Does this discussion helps [Report Formula - Percentage per row per column (not entire table)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/report-formula-percentage-per-row-per-column-not-entire-table?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Report Formula - Percentage per row per column (not entire table)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/report-formula-percentage-per-row-per-column-not-entire-table)

Comment: Not quite, I'm looking to calculate a specific percentage of the Quote amount field, using the Forecast Category as criteria, the proposed solution estimates the percentage each row represents compared to the total.